# Rewrite `git` History of a Large File

Tags: git

I am trying to remove some large files from my `git` repository.

After a fair amount of browsing I have come across the following solution,

```bash
git_delete_file() {
    git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch $1" --prune-empty
    git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
    git reflog expire --expire=now --all
    git gc --aggressive --prune=now
}

git_file_space() {
    git rev-list --all --objects | 
        git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | 
        grep blob |
        sort -k3nr |
        head -n 20
}
```

However, when I run `git_delete_file large/file/path` and then `git_file_space` the files are persisting. I have not tried to download `git-filter-repo` but I am considering it a last resort.

Regards
Jordan

Comment: `git-filter-repo` is more conventional for this anyway; no reason to avoid it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in the Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository)

Comment: Not exactly, my question was why `git filter-branch` was not actually removing the file, not how to remove the file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have not tried to download git-filter-repo but I am considering it a last resort.

It is true you need to [install it](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) (after installing Python), but after that, removing a file is simply, using [path-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_path_based_filtering):

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path 'path/to/large/file'
```

That seems easier than the all `filter-branch` + `update-ref` + `reflog` + `gc` workflow.