# GIT LFS installed, tracked the right files, but still errors while pushing Unity Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, git-lfs

I followed different guidelines for uploading / pushing large files that are in Unity Projects. I tracked all large files, I added GIT ignore file. But I still get these errors. What can I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not push your Library folder to your Git repository. This library is automatically generated by Unity and can safely be generated by anyone cloning the project. Consider adding a .gitignore file with appropriate excludes. A sample can be found at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore

Comment: Thanks Bart. Noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if you are supposed to track *.so files.
As you can see in this [`.gitattributes` file](https://gist.github.com/Srfigie/77b5c15bc5eb61733a74d34d10b3ed87), `*.so` are not supposed to be tracked by LFS, and should be ignored (see [`Unity.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore))
See also "[How To Set Up Git LFS Into Your Unity Project](https://adamwreed93.medium.com/how-to-set-up-git-lfs-into-your-unity-project-9fd276305fe7)" from [Adam Reed](https://github.com/adamwreed93).

If that is the case, you need to `git rm` those files first, before your commit and push. And possibly [use `git filter-repo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75077599/6309) to remove those same files from your past commits if they were committed before.

Comment: Thanks! I feel followed the steps and it worked!